# How to periodically update my local DB with changes from the Production DB

Tags: oracle

I want to know if there is a similar type of tool to say subversion for Oracle.

I am in a bit of a situation where I need to debug potential coding or data issues.
The problem is that the Data is quite big and to do a update every 24h or so will just be impossible. But Im thinking if there is a way to run a script that could look at the local and production DB, determine the difference between them ( production DB being the wanted changes ). and update the local DB with those new records/changes.

Is there something out there that might do this type of thing?

This will be for oracle 11gR2 databases

Comment: [Replication with Oracle Streams](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/data-integration/twp-streams-11gr1-134658.pdf) ?

Comment: Not directly related, but : You might need to `scrub` the data. It is not a good idea to have production data anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check whether the `DBLINK` works between the two oracle server 
the db link tutorial id http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Database_link

If the `DBLINK` works create a procedure like

```
PROCEDURE p1
IS 
BEGIN
 --MERGE SCRIPTS to your table
END;
```

call the same in `DBMS_JOBS` for each day like below

```
exec dbms_job.submit(:v_JobNo, 'proc1;', TRUNC(SYSDATE)+1, 'TRUNC(SYSDATE)+1');
```

for more information about jobs refer here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_job.htm#BABHCBFD

if the `DBLINK` doesnot works you have to go some other middleware tools

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks @Exhausted. I will investigate this now.