# Chianed replication in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, replication, oracle-golden-gate

I have Oracle 11g DB in server A,server B and Server C.
I have to set up replication from Server A--> Server B--> Server C.
In my sql i am able to do successfully ,since i am new to Oracle,can some please guide me if this is possible in Oracle 11g as well,if so where should i start from.
I have gone through various options ,since Golden gate seems to be way forward can some please let me know how to start?

I have tried doing replication using Oracle streams but faced few problems in case of link failure.

Comment: read `DBLINKS` from here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm#ADMIN12083 which might helpful to you

Comment: shared db is not the requirement though,basically i need some kind of mirroring technique in 11g

Comment: please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27819960/how-to-periodically-update-my-local-db-with-changes-from-the-production-db/27820057#27820057